# Explicit counter-example for $\exp(\int A)' = A \exp(\int A)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

If $A \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ is a matrix it is known for the purpose of ODE theory that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}e^{tA} = A e^{tA}.
$$
It is also known that this does not easily generalizes to non autonomous case:
$$
\exp\left( \int_0^t A(s)ds \right) X_0
$$
does not give necessarily the solution of the Cauchy problem
$$
\dot X (t) = A(t) X(t),\quad X(0)=X_0.
$$
I am wondering if there are easy and explicit situations where this phenomenon could be observed, that is $A : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ smooth but
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \exp\left( \int_0^t A(s)ds \right) \neq A(t) \exp\left( \int_0^t A(s)ds \right).
$$
Actually any discussion on the differentiation of the above quantity is of interest.

Comment: I guess you need an example where the values $A(s)$ do not commute with each other.

Comment: $A(s)$ and $A'(s)$ do not commute?

Comment: Can you write what you obtain for $\exp(\int A)'$ without assuming that the $A(t)$ commute, using the series for $\exp$? For example $A(t)=B+Ct$ with $BC\ne CB$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then
$B(t)=\int_0^t A(s)ds = \begin{bmatrix} t & {1 \over 2} t^2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and
$B^n(t) = t^n A({1 \over 2} t)$ for $n \ge 1$.
Hence $\Phi(t)=e^{B(t)} = I + (e^t-1) A({ 1\over 2} t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^t & {1 \over 2} t (e^t -1 ) \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $\dot{\Phi}(t)= \begin{bmatrix} e^t & {1 \over 2} (t e^t+e^t -1 ) \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and
$A(t)\Phi(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^t & {1 \over 2} (t e^t+t ) \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Assuming I have made no mistake in computation,
$\dot{\Phi}(t) \ne A(t)\Phi(t)$ for $t \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but it could lead to constructing counterexamples:

Theorem. If $A:I\to \mathbb R^{d\times d}$, continuous, where $I$ interval, and
$$
A(s)A(t)=A(t)A(s), \quad \text{for all $s,t\in I$},
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\exp\Big(\int_\tau^t A(s)\,ds\Big)=A(t)\exp\Big(\int_\tau^t A(s)\,ds\Big).
$$

Comment: Voted up because unexplained downvotes bug me :-).